Safety and Ventilation Concerns for 3D Resin Printers: Understanding the Risks and Recommended Practices
I recently purchased a 3D resin printer and have noticed that it produces fumes during operation. I've come across advice suggesting the use of masks and specialized ventilation setups, and recommendations to avoid being in the same room as the printer. However, I'm having difficulty finding formal or scientific recommendations about the safety of these fumes.
Specifically, I have a few questions:

Are the fumes produced by 3D resin printers generally considered hazardous, and is it truly necessary to avoid the room where the printer is operating?
Do the fumes remain a concern even after 24 hours, or do they dissipate over time?
What are the recommended safety practices and ventilation solutions that laboratories or industrial settings use for managing fumes (are there any standart for resin?)

I’m seeking guidance based on scientific evidence and established safety protocols rather than anecdotal advice. Any information on formal recommendations or safety standards would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. What about printing in my yard instead of a close room? Is it dangerous to plants nearby? can I be in the yard some time after printing? I’m concerned about potential risks to both plants and people.

While some here might be able to answer directly I suggest providing additional information about the resins (perhaps commercial source). Such products are accompanied by an SDS (safety data sheet) which lists composition and risks. // "can I be in the yard some time after printing?" You will not pose a risk to others, the fumes pose a risk to you. Doing this with proper ventilation should minimize risks (but consider that when bbq-ing you should not inhale the smoke).

Fumes emitted by 3D resin printers contain Volatile organic compounds and some ultrafine particles that can pose a risk to human health. Make sure you have good ventilation which would certainly aid in fumes dissipating however they do dissipate naturally. To filter out organic compounds, it is recommended to have a mask and gloves. Ventilation is the most important thing though. You can do it safely in a good ventilated room with good precautions as mentioned. As long as you are being safe, there is no serious concern in being in the room when 3D printing occurs.
Here is a good website where you can research and learn more.
https://printingit3d.com/are-resin-printer-fumes-toxic-what-you-need-to-know/
